# Create multiple files using a file that contains the file names using bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to create different files in a single directory using a file that contains the file names. For example if the file contains

`file1,file2`

it will create two files file1.md and file2.md in the directory.

I am using the command `touch {$(cat file)}.md` but this creates a single file file1,file2.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace the commas with newlines using `tr` and read the result into an array:

```
mapfile -t fnames < <(tr ',' '\n' < file)
touch "${fnames[@]/%/.md}"
```

The parameter expansion `${fnames[@]/%/.md}` replaces the end of each array element (`%`) with suffix `.md`.

Comment: This works. But why does `touch {file1,file2}.md` create `file1.md` and `file2.md` while using cat it doesn't?

Comment: The brace expansion is evaluated _before_ the command substitution of `$(cat file)`. You could do an ugly `eval` like `eval "touch {$(cat file)}.md"` instead...

Comment: Is there any advantage in converting to newline separated format and then using `mapfile`, compared to say `IFS=, read -a fnames < file` ?

Comment: @steeldriver Not if the file only contains one line.

Answer (score 1):

Just convert the comma to a newline and then read the file names:

```
sed 's/,/\n/g' file | while read fileName; do touch "$fileName".md; done
```

Or:

```
tr , '\n' < file | while read fileName; do touch "$fileName".md; done
```

Comment: Thanks for this! But do you know why `touch {$(cat file)}.md` doesn't work?

Comment: @TitanX it does work. You are telling it to create a file whose name is the contents of `file`. Those contents are `file1,file2` so that's what it creates.

Comment: But `touch {file1,file2}.md` creates two different files `file1.md` and `file2.md` and `cat file` exactly returns `file1,file2`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
tr ',' '\n' < file | xargs -0 -I {} touch {}.md
```

Comment: This creates one file with two newlines. Have you tried?

Comment: @Freddy Yes I have, and in my tests it creates files separately

Comment: I'm copying the command as it is in my answer to discard doubts, and copied the string of files from the question.